# Getting specific data from a string with jQuery

Tags: jquery

What I want to do is create a variable with the data from the firstName section of this string, that can be used in other places in the code.

I've tried a few different methods but only seen similar examples around extracting specific characters from the string.

Any suggestions on how to go about this?

```
var userStuff = {
    firstName: "Tester",
    lastname: "McTester",
    email: "test@test.com"
};
```

Comment: You mean `var variableName = userStuff.firstName`?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Wow! I feel silly haha, thanks that worked a treat!

Answer (score 1):

u can get get the property with this exepretion

const  {  firstName  }  = userStuff